# I don't know the meaning of the ROS code,and I can't understand the example of ros wiki

Tags: c++, ros

I expect the detailed description of this code. Thanks

```
rosbag::Bag  bag(rosbag, rosbag::bagmode::Read);//read bag?
rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));//create a view on a bag.
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view){}//what?
const std::string& topic_name = m.getTopic();
if (topic_name == topics[0])//what?
{
  dvs_msgs::EventArray::ConstPtr msg = 
  m.instantiate<dvs_msgs::EventArray>();
  if (msg != NULL)
  {
    if(msg->events.empty())
    {
      continue;
    }
    const ros::Time& stamp = msg->events[0].ts;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rosbag::Bag bag;
bag.open("test.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Read);
```

Yeap, in this way you can read the bag file

```
std::vector<std::string> topics;
rosbag::View view(bag, rosbag::TopicQuery(topics));
```

This will iterate through all the topic information in the provided bag file and push back into topics

```
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view){}//what?
```

you have a mistake here, **BOOST_FOREACH** is macro, and here how it can be used

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH
```

Include header file and then

```
foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view)
{
    const std::string& topic_name = m.getTopic();
    if (topic_name == topics[0])//what?
    {
      dvs_msgs::EventArray::ConstPtr msg = 
      m.instantiate<dvs_msgs::EventArray>();
      if (msg != NULL)
      {
         if(msg->events.empty())
         {
          continue;
         }
        const ros::Time& stamp = msg->events[0].ts;
      }
   }
}
```

This will iterate through each of the messages, `m.getTopic()` this will get the topic corresponding to the current message, `msg` is the current message, and `stamp` is the time which this message was recorded.

Comment: thanks a lot  and I  want know "topic_name = m.getTopic();"这句话会返回m种所有的值吗？还是第几个值呢？

Comment: Hope you know about rostopic (http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic), if so m.getTopic() will return the corresponding rostopic such as /sensor1/lidar/pointclod